# Is it possible to express a theorem that states which constructors have been applied?

Tags: coq

Given this simple language and `eval` definition:

```
Inductive  exp : Type :=
| lit : nat -> exp
| add : exp -> exp -> exp
.

Inductive eval : exp -> nat -> Prop :=
| eval_lit: forall n, eval (lit n) n
| eval_add0: forall e n, eval e n -> eval (add (lit 0) e) n
| eval_add: forall e1 e2 n1 n2,  ~(e1 = lit 0) -> eval e1 n1 -> 
                                 eval e2 n2 -> eval (add e1 e2) (n1 + n2)
.
```

I want to be able to express that if there is a valid instance of the form `eval (add e1 e2) e` then either the constructor `eval_add0` or `eval_add` had been used. Is it possible to do this? And if so, is that provable? This is the incomplete code of I would like to achieve:

```
Theorem appplied_constructor: forall e1 e2, exists e, eval (add e1 e2) e -> 
           (* either the constructor eval_add0 or eval_add had to be applied *).
Proof.
...
Qed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly express which constructor was used, but what you can do is work backwards from the constructor's type to figure what you know if that constructor was used. This is exactly what the inversion tactic does. What you'll need to do is manually state what you know about `e1` and `e2` given that you have `eval (add ..) ..`. For example:

```
Theorem appplied_constructor: forall e1 e2, (exists e, eval (add e1 e2) e) ->
                                      (e1 = lit 0) \/
                                      (~e1 = lit 0 /\
                                        exists n1 n2, eval e1 n1 /\
                                                eval e2 n2).
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct H as [e ?].
  inversion H; subst; eauto 10.
Qed.
```

You stated your theorem with `exists e`, so I followed that pattern and didn't refer to `e` in the conclusion. However, rather than assuming `exists e, ...`, you can just say `forall e` and then refer back to that `e`:

```
Theorem appplied_constructor': forall e1 e2 e, eval (add e1 e2) e ->
                                      (eval e2 e /\ e1 = lit 0) \/
                                      (~e1 = lit 0 /\
                                        exists n1 n2, eval e1 n1 /\
                                                 eval e2 n2 /\
                                                 n1 + n2 = e).
Proof.
  intros.
  inversion H; subst; eauto 10.
Qed.
```